# How to compare characters in two strings to sort them alphabetically? (without c string library functions)

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison, character

I searched through a bit and couldn't find any comparison with characters that didn't use String library functions like strcmp, so hoping this question isn't a repeat. I'm coming from Java and am a bit new to C language. I'm trying to compare two strings (saved in the same array) to sort them alphabetically, but attempting to do so without C string library functions, and can't seem to figure this out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for (i = 0; i < TotalStrings; i++) { /* TotalStrings is the number of strings in the array */
if (length[i] < length[i+1]) { /* compares length of both strings, saved in a different array */
 for (j = 0; j < length[i]; j++) {
   if (Strings[i][j] > Strings[i+1][j]) {
       char temp = Strings[i];
       Strings[i] = Strings[i+1];
       Strings[i+1] = temp;
       j = length[i];
   }
  }
}
if (length[i] > length[i+1]) { /* compares length of both strings, saved in a different array */
 for (j = 0; j < length[i+1]; j++) {
   if (Strings[i][j] > Strings[i+1][j]) {
       char temp = Strings[i];
       Strings[i] = Strings[i+1];
       Strings[i+1] = temp;
       j = length[i];
       }
      }
     }
```

The line if (Strings[i][j] > Strings[i+1][j]) is where I'm stuck. As I've been taught, the first bracket in a 2D array holds the string, and the second bracket points to the characters? I'm not sure how to go about exactly comparing the characters of these strings. Pretty sure trying to do it as I am (like I would numbers) is off.

Also, not sure if this is related to my code above (due to it being unfinished or because temp is of type char and Strings is a 2D array of type Char; but I'm getting an error pointing to the equals sign in the statement below:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[1000]' from type 'char'
            Strings[i+1] = temp;
```

**Edit: looking at my code now, I can see a huge flaw in that it will run until a character at the same index in string[x] comes after the character in string[x+1], and then change the strings all together; which is wrong. I'll change my code to correct that, but am still unaware if I'm comparing chars the right way.**

Comment: Are *non-string* functions allowed? Such as `qsort()`. If they are, that could make it easier for you (although granted, `qsort()` can be confusing).

Comment: Also, can we please see how you've declared `Strings`?

Comment: @TimČas I declared Strings as `Char Strings[TotalStrings][MaxLength] `. Non-string functions are fine, but I'm trying to learn how to write a loop to check each individual character (if necessary)

Comment: Did you copy a huge block of code twice into the question, or is it what your code really looks like?  There are 7 `{` and not one `}`, so it is hard to know what you've really done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I had a block of code and copy/pasted part of it to show the distinction between what happens if length[i] is > length[i+1]; Yes that is my code but what I copied from my client stops at `j = length[i];`. Everything after that is a copy of the above statement but with the if/for loops switched to show what would happen if the length of String[i] happens to be greater than the length of String[i+1]; I will mend the curly brackets so that the formatting reflects what the end code will have.

Comment: There's still one more open `{` than close `}`.  Also, with the compiler error message, we need to see the variable declarations.  You should be seeing more compilation errors than just the one you quote, I think.  Are you both sorting and comparing in this code, or just comparing?  I think you're doing both.  Do you accidentally ignore all pairs of strings that are the same length?  Normally, the lengths of the strings is largely immaterial for the comparison.  I'm not sure about the `j = length[i];` assignments after the swap code, either.

Comment: In **C**, _string_ is a `char` array up to and including the terminating null character `'\0'`.  This post uses "string" in a potentially non-standard way as code says "length of both strings, saved in a different array".  To best answer this post, please clarify: Is this a string compare as C defines a string, or is this some other compare? If some other compare - detail this post's meaning of "string".   This is not a question of what functions one may use, but a request for your "string" details.

Answer (score 1):

Since @Nunzio Tocci have showed the problem in your code.

the problem in your code was,
assigning a pointer to char to a char variable and vise versa.

You can improve the code by breaking it down in to functions, like one for comparing strings and another to sort it, since you cannot use `strcpy` also(because you said no standard library calls ), you can write a function for string copy too, and implement the code.

below is an example, you can look into it and start your own from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Compare two strings, returns -1, 0 ,1
int string_compare(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    // perfrom null dereferencing error checking
    while( (*s1==*s2) && *s1 )
        s1++,s2++;
    return *s1 < *s2 ? -1 : *s1 > *s2;
}

// Copy s2 into s1
int string_copy(char *s1, const char* s2){
    // perfrom null dereferencing error checking
    while( (*s1++ = *s2++) )
        ;
    return 0;
}

// Sort the array of string
char *const *const string_sort(char *const *const str, const int     totalString,const int strMaxLen) {

    char *temp = malloc(strMaxLen);  // Using temp for swapping
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < totalString; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < totalString - 1; j++) {
            if (string_compare(str[j], str[j + 1]) > 0) {
                string_copy(temp,str[j]);
                string_copy(str[j],str[j + 1]);
                string_copy(str[j + 1],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    free(temp);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    /* No of strings/ can be known at runtime also
       since we are not using array */
    const int totalString = 10; 
    const int strLen = 1000;    // string length 

    // Pointer to store address of an the array of string.
    char **str = NULL;  
    int i;

    /* Allocate memory for storing the 
       address of "totalString" no of stirngs */
    str = malloc(totalString*sizeof(char*));

    /* allocate memory to store a string 
       witb 'strLen' length */
    for(i = 0; i < totalString; ++i)
        str[i] = malloc(strLen);

    /* Read from the user or
       any external source ( ex: file) */
    for(i = 0; i < totalString; ++i)
        scanf("%s",str[i]);

    /* sort the strings */
    string_sort(str,totalString,strLen);

    /* print then */
    for( i = 0; i < totalString; ++i )
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);

    for( i = 0; i < totalString; ++i )
        free(str[i]);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where the flaw in the original code was, what your code does differently, and why it is supposed to work? Dumping a piece of code without any comments isn't very helpful.

Comment: Note: `&& *s2` not needed with `while(*s1 && *s2 && (*s1==*s2))`.  Suggest putting `*s1==*s2` first: `while((*s1==*s2) && *s1)`.

Comment: @chux i agree with not needing `&& *s2` but the order of `(*s1==*s2)` does not make any difference i think.

Comment: The order does not make a big difference.  Yet the left side is evaluated before the right.  When the first parts of the 2 strings are the same - no difference.  But when the strings differ: which is more likely: the 2 `char` differing or `s1` ending?  Faster to test the compare that is more likely to fail.  In my experience, it has been `*s1==*s2`.  Of course this depends on the data set and likely best to code in the way most maintainable.

Comment: @chux ya, its depend on the data set, but the point you made is right, it is best to increase performance of the code for the most common data set.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED (see below)
About the error:
It looks like
`char temp = Strings[i];`
should be:
<strike>`char *temp = Strings[i];`</strike>
I don't know why the compiler didn't error when you assigned a character variable with a pointer, but that is what looks to be the problem.
I would recommend reading up on [pointers](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) in C, especially if you come from Java.

In regard to your original question:
It looks like you are comparing them the right way.
Also, yes as you've been taught, the first bracket in a 2D array holds the string, and the second bracket points to the characters.

UPDATE:
As Jonathan said, temp should actually be:
`char temp[1000];`
But since you aren't using the standard library functions you will need to copy the strings manually.

Comment: Actually, it looks to me more like `temp` should be `char temp[1000];` and the assignments should be string copy operations.